# Rancher -- pull new image via API

Tags: docker

I've got CI set up correctly to compile the project code and push it to Docker Hub. Next, I'd like to add a step to CI so that, after the image is pushed, Rancher upgrades the service it's linked to and pulls down the new image.

However, according to the [documentation (see bottom)](http://docs.rancher.com/rancher/api/api-resources/service/), the API call for `upgrade` must contain a massive JSON object with many pieces of data included. My initial plan for testing was just to hardcode this JSON object, to see if it worked, but the documentation is unclear on where to get this lode of information.

**What would be the best way to run an `upgrade` on my service from CI?**

Answer (score 0):

first get the service, it will contain a `launchConfig`. Then an upgrade and pass in the launchConfig, changing the fields of what you want to change.

Comment: My experience is that you need to send a "full" launchconfig, not just the changed fields. If you for example omit the "environment" attribute, you'll remove any existing environment variables from the service.

Comment: @Trondh exactly. Take the launchConfig, edit the fields, then send the whole thing.